# What does ":this(100)" mean in a C# method declaration?

Tags: c#

What does ":this(100)" mean in a C# method declaration?

While reading MDSN docs I came across it in line 6 of the following code:

```
  public class Stack
    {
       readonly int m_Size; 
       int m_StackPointer = 0;
       object[] m_Items; 
       public Stack():this(100)
       {}   
       public Stack(int size)
       {
          m_Size = size;
          m_Items = new object[m_Size];
       }
    }
```

Comment: That's not a regular method, it's a constructor. Besides, programming questions should be asked on [so] as they are off topic here on Super User. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) in our help center for more about what topics are allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Stack()
```

Is the default constructor

```
public Stack(int size)
```

Is the parametric constructor

```
public Stack():this(100)
```

Means the default constructor will call parametric constructor with parameter size as 100.

Refer to [this Construtor](http://www.dotnetperls.com/this-constructor) for more information

> This is used in constructors. It is used to overload the constructors
>   in a C# program. It allows code to be shared between the constructors.
>   Constructor initializers, which use the this-keyword, prove useful in
>   nontrivial classes.